# Launch method when window (and its views) appear in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a multi Window (A,B,C) application. User can close Window A(transparent and buttonless) by pressing a specific button on interface, at some point he can reopen it by click another button.
It works great, by i need reset some values when window is opened again.

I know that `awakeFromNib` is called from window and from view but only once, it doesn't be call again at window reopen. Is there a method that Window (and Views ?) call when window reopen ? something like viewWDidAppear for IOS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register for the `UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification` for that.

Comment: Ok! wonderful, what you think about use `-(void)becomeMainWindow` is it a good method too ?

Comment: that's good to override in a subclass not to be called directly